# ag-Grid - how to force custom sorting after data is added or modified

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to use custom sorting on a column in ag-Grid in my `Ionic 4/Angular 8` application.

I have a sample application [here](https://github.com/pjc2007/aggrid-expander.git), or on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/pjc2007/aggrid-expander?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.page.ts) I can't get it to run on Stackblitz, but it definatley runs locally,

At any rate a couple of things to note are I want the grid to run in virtual mode (eg may have 1000 rows of data), and also I have set `this.gridOptions.immutableData = true;` to handle my data from `ng/rx`.

Also I am using a component as a cell template, but I think we can ignore that here (using an existing example)

I wish to have the rows sorted, and so calling my `dateComparator` function both

- When I first load the data
- If I have any data added or updated

To emulate new data coming in from a server, I have an add button which calls the `add` method.

I have added a `comparator` on the column...

```js
        public ngAfterViewInit(): void {                
            const self = this;
            this.gridOptions.immutableData = true;
            this.gridOptions.animateRows = true
            this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs([
            {
                    headerName: 'myheader',
                    comparator: self.dateComparator,
                    sortable: true,
                    field: 'equipment',
                    cellStyle: { padding: 0 },        
                    cellRendererFramework: TemplateRendererComponent,              
                    cellRendererParams: {
                        ngTemplate: this.itemCard
                    },        
                },
            ]);

            this.setData();
            }

    private dateComparator(valueA, valueB, nodeA, nodeB, isInverted): number {
       console.log('sorting');
       return 1;
     }
```

However, when I load the grid, or call the above add method, my `dateComparator` is not being called. It is only called if I click the column header.

I have tried calling `this.gridOptions.api.redrawRows()` but this does not cause it to sort. I can't see any other obvious `sort` function to call.

My question is, how can I have this sorting applied automatically without clicking the column header (ie when I load or update my data)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To sort a column by default, you have to specify the sorting attribute in the colDef -

```
sort: 'desc', // asc or desc
```

You can also do this after grid is initialized using sorting api -

```
var sort = [
  {
    colId: 'country',
    sort: 'asc',
  },
  {
    colId: 'sport',
    sort: 'asc',
  },
];
this.gridApi.setSortModel(sort); // provide sort model here
```

Now, when your data is updated and you need to let the grid know to maintain the sorting as per your custom comparator, you need to call -  `onSortChanged()`

As per docs-

> **onSortChanged()**
>   Gets the grid to act as if the sort was changed. Useful if you update some values and want to get the grid to
>   reorder them according to the new values.

Example on applying sort model [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/#example-sorting-api)

Comment: thankyou very much! It seemed just adding the sort: 'asc' now made my `comparator` method now be called both when first adding the data and also when I added new data. IN my simple test, I haven't even needed to call the `onSortChanged()`, but will keep this in mind if once I start more complex updates I don't see the sorting working my itself.